# How can I make JFormattedTextField use $1.55, but store the value as the Integer 155?

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

Almost everything I've ever read about Java says don't use float or double for currency, but it seems like everything in Swing tries to force you to do exactly that if you want to input / display currency values that have decimal places (aka exactly what most people want to do).

I can use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` with a `NumberFormatter` and `JFormattedTextField`, but I can't figure out how to get it to display decimal places without using `Float` or `Double`.  I've got to be overlooking something simple.

How can I make my currency fields display `$1.55`, accept input as `1.55` and store the input as an Integer with a value of `155` (cents)?

Comment: BigDecimal is your friend for exact doing currency math

Comment: @kleopatra: as long as you're not doing so many of them that simply using Java objects becomes a bottleneck.  To reuse your "stock market" argument: I somehow very much doubt that high-frequency trading, where every milliseconds count, is done using Java *BigDecimal*...  I'm pretty sure "integer math" saves the day here (not too sure about Java being used in high-frequency trading that said ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do math on formatters. What you should do is have a member variable of your pojo holding the price in cents. Something like:

```
private long priceInDollarCents;
```

Then you can have a getter which will return this in dollars. Something like:

```
public double getPriceInDollars() {
    return (double)priceInDollarCents/100;
}
```

This is what you'll pass into your formatter.

Comment: two decimals are not enough in the financial world (see f.i. stock exchange values)

Comment: @kleopatra: Most probably yes. As it's not enough for astro-physics calculations etc.

Comment: @cherouvim I'm guessing that I don't need to worry about converting back and forth to `double` as long as it's strictly for input / output.  More specifically, is there any way that converting between `double` and `long` could cause problems if I'm NOT doing any calculations or comparisons with the `double` values?  Since everyone says not to use `double` for currency, I was worried about converting my values into `double` even if it was just for editing.

Comment: If you can ask the user to enter the price at dollar cents then that's better (for you as a programmer). Sometimes though this is not acceptable. The users need to be entering dollars and you should be manipulating cents.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

[image]

**CustomizedField.java**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class CustomizedField extends JTextField
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomizedField(int size)
    {
        super(size);
        setupFilter();
    }

    public int getCents()
    {
        String s = getText();
        System.out.println(s);
        if(s.endsWith(".")) s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s) * 100;
        return (int) d;
    }

    private void setupFilter()
    {

        ((AbstractDocument) getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter()
        {

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
            {
                check(fb, offset, text, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
            {
                check(fb, offset, text, attr);
            }

            private void check(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()));
                sb.insert(offset, text);
                if(!containsOnlyNumbers(sb.toString())) return;
                fb.insertString(offset, text, attr);
            }

            private boolean containsOnlyNumbers(String text)
            {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]{0,1})?[\\d]*.([\\d]{0,2})?");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
                boolean isMatch = matcher.matches();
                return isMatch;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing CustomizedField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final CustomizedField cField = new CustomizedField(10);
        final JTextField output = new JTextField(10);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Print cents!");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                output.setText(cField.getCents() + " cents");
            }
        });

        frame.add(cField);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.add(output);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```